# Acorn System 1 - is it a collectable?

Tags: 6502, acorn

I have one of these things gathering dust at home:

[Acorn System 1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acorn_System_1)

I have the original manual (when I find it?) too.

It did work, the last time I powered it up, 35 years ago.

Should I throw it in the bin or sell it?

Comment: Oh, I could point you to a very specific bin - it would sit quite well next to a 380Z :)) Having said that, this question is not realy for RC, as it asks about opinion, which is explicit off topic.

Comment: We hacked the disk/disc on the 380Z and changed all the error messages.

Comment: Agree with Raffzahn re: suitability for the site. But if the choice is between binning it and selling it, definitely sell it. Without being confident enough to be more numerically specific, profit will outweigh effort.

Comment: Would it be more on topic if it asked where yo can find buyers for retro computers?

Comment: What did eBay say when you searched?

Comment: I have never seen one listed there.

Comment: @birdwes if you still have the unit and would like it to be used as part of a school STEM education project I run please get in touch. I have one already that I take on school visits, but a spare would be handy as they are a bit fragile. FYI: There's also a retro project to make up a replica. Google takes care of my email for 'linker3000' - or a Web search will pick me up at places like 6502.org and twitter. Happy to send more details. Also: https://imgur.com/gallery/f7zZR

Answer (score 4):

Ebay have a special category for retro computers
There is also the UK based https://www.sellmyretro.com/ were you can try to sell it.
I am sure that most countries also have their local sites where to sell things like this.
Also, serach the web i your local area for Acorn user groups. Even if they probably are more into the slightly newer Acorn computers, there is a big chance at least some one there is interested in a Acorn System 1 to get a complete set on the shelf at home.

Comment: I don't understand why the OP did not look on eBay before posting here

Answer (score 3):

Someone would most certainly be interested in this. Whether it's worth your while is the next question.

Comment: It's not going to be worth as much as https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_I

Comment: Well no, that's true, because Acorn isn't a trillion dollar company today.

Comment: their ARM chips are in your mobile phone.... and Softbank sell the verilog design to Apple's chip manufacturers.

Comment: @birdwes It's anything between zero and _maybe_ 60-100 quid. Ofc, you could always be lucky and hit some nostalgic fool paying more. Not likely but said to have happened.    ... thinking of it, I may even know someone interested not far from you, living south of Swindon.

Comment: It's not for sale at the moment.   This was just a "test"

Comment: @birdwes I would happily buy it assuming you would sell it for a reasonable price.  ;-)

Comment: @birdwes not nice wasting other people' s time. We have also some people here often asking very unreasonable prices for items they deem collectable, and the strategy is buying elsewhere, buying them off-country or simply not buying. I have seen people asking 500 euros for equipment worthy 60-80. No, your junk is not a "collectable", at least in the next decade or two.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro, I did not mean to offend with my jocular question of discarding it.  I am now in a dilemma, do I keep it for a few more years, sell it, or donate it to a museum.

Bletchley park already have one:  https://www.zdnet.com/pictures/acorns-land-at-bletchley-park/

Comment: No offense taken. We do have a problem here in my location, some people avoid buying here speccy and timex related material and prefer to buy in Poland. Many equipments sold here do not work, are not well kept, and some people is out there for a quick buck

Comment: @birdwes if you still have the unit and would like it to be used as part of a school STEM education project I run please get in touch. I have one already that I take on school visits, but a spare would be handy as they are a bit fragile. FYI: There's also a retro project to make up a replica. Google takes care of my email for 'linker3000' - or a Web search will pick me up at places like 6502.org and twitter. Happy to send more details. Also: https://imgur.com/gallery/f7zZR